# Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.0 migration with Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

After migration AGP to 7.0.0, some declarations are deprecated and should be replaced by property. How to replace declarations as `flavorDimensions` or `resConfigs` when the property is just a value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I overlooked that thoose values (`flavorDimensions`, `resourceConfigurations`...) are mutable, so I can simply add new value

```
flavorDimensions.add("dimensionName")
```

Comment: flavorDimensions property seems to be still unstable in Gradle 7.0.0 - 7.4.0   (@get:Incubating)